# Is it safe to use SYS_GUID() as unique ID in an Oracle table?

Tags: oracle11g, guid

I have following table DDL. Can I safely use ROWKEY to identify a row uniquely? I don't want to use Sequence/On-Insert trigger thing.

```
CREATE
TABLE T_SEGMENT
(
    SEGMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(15),
    ROWKEY VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT sys_guid()
)
```

[image]

Comment: You can. I'm afraid that you waste a lot of space. The PK column is 3x bigger than business data.

Comment: If you're going this route, you might want to consider setting `rowkey` to `sys_guid` in a trigger rather than (or in addition to) as the default. If you don't then the default can be overwritten by absolutely anything. You might also want to consider using `RAW(16)` as the type for `ROWKEY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking "is sys_guid() guaranteed to return a unique value", yes.  Well, almost yes-- part of the GUID is the result of a random number generator so it's theoretically possible that you'd get a duplicate, it's just incredibly unlikely.

Of course, if you are using a GUID to uniquely identify a row, it would make sense to define the `rowkey` as the primary key and it would make sense for that key to be the first column in the table.